# Can I have GFCI receptacles on the same circuit as normal receptacles?

Tags: electrical, gfci

I am looking at a few books and they all show samples of circuits, but never tell or show if you can mix receptacle types.

I have a circuit running to 2 bedrooms for my power outlets. The are on 12/2 and a total of 6 outlets. I wanted to add 2 GFCI outlets for the deck outside and wanted to know if it was ok to add those outlets to this circuit since I can still add 4 more outlets?

Can't seem to find sample diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is accepted and code.  The GFCI will only protect what is downstream though.

[image]

Also as picture shows you must connect duplex to load for it to be protected.  The load will be labeled on the receptacle.

Comment: GFCI does not protect everything *downstream*, only things connected to the **LOAD** terminals.